# Document is not ready in DocumentReady event?

Tags: c#, .net, awesomium

I am using [Awesomium 1.7.0.5](http://awesomium.com) in order to load a page, fill some textboxes and click a button. I am trying to fill a textbox using an example from this thread: http://answers.awesomium.com/questions/857/webcontrol-type-in-webbrowser.html

Here is my code (I am using WPF control):

```
        private void WbAwsOnDocumentReady(object sender, UrlEventArgs urlEventArgs)
        {
            if (wbAws == null || !wbAws.IsLive)
              return;

            //Thread.Sleep(555);

            dynamic document = (JSObject)wbAws.ExecuteJavascriptWithResult("document");

            if (document == null)
              return;

            using (document)
            {
                dynamic textbox = document.getElementById("email");

                if (textbox == null)
                  return;

                using (textbox)
                {
                    textbox.value = "gaaffa"; 
                }

            }
        }
```

It works but only with Thread.Sleep for 0.1-0.5 sec. Otherwise document is empty (not null) and/or textbox is null.
What should I do? Why it is not ready in DocumentReadyEvent?

Comment: Did you tried FinishLoading event?

Comment: hm... There is no such event.

Comment: i'm working with ver 1.6,it has this event.but you can check if document == null run WbAwsOnDocumentReady method again until set text box value

Comment: Document is not null. Also I tried while (wbAws.IsLoading) Sleep(...); but it doesn't work because it somehow doesn't change to false in that way, although it changes to false after executing JS scripts.

Comment: It tells you that a frame completed loading, note that a URL can produce multiple frames.  But you know nothing about any scripting code that modifies the document.  No events for it and Thread.Sleep() is not safe.  You have to poll with a DispatcherTimer, checking if the expected element is available.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is how I solved it:

```
     WbAws.LoadingFrameCompleted += OnLoadingFrameCompleted;
     WbAws.Source = new Uri("http://google.com");

private void OnLoadingFrameCompleted(...)
{ 
   if (webView == null || !webView.IsLive || 
         webView.ParentView != null || !e.IsMainFrame)
     return;

    LoadingFrameCompleted -= OnLoadingFrameCompleted;

    // do something
}
```

LoadingFrameCompleted instead of DocumentReady and because it fires not only when I need it but also on app startup I subscribe to it just before navigating and unsubscribe after it. Also checking that it IsMainFrame.

**edit**: but with this solution it sometimes throws exception that document is not ready. So I am also waiting for it using Thread.Sleep.

Answer (score 0):

Very old question. but for someone like me, who is facing this problem-
use `LoadingFrameCompleted` event with `WebControl.IsNavigating == false` and `e.IsMainFrame == true` condition.
if these conditions are true in this event then page is finished loading and you are ready to get HTML content.